# Compare the characters of two strings and return the index of the character found

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the characters of two Strings

- String string1 = "ABC";
- String string2 = "ABCCB";

so here for example if we compare the strings together , 'A' in string1 is found in index 0 in string1 'B' in index '1' and so long,so by comparing the strings I should get a number which is 01221, I know in java it has the `contains()` , `indexOf()` , but I can't think of how this can be achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your `string2` char by char and use `string1.indexOf(c)`. You'll get the sequence of numbers.